# c# how to close app. after 3 wrong login tries

Tags: c#, authentication

```
private void btnPrijava_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HotelValentinoDataSet.KorisniciDataTable korisnikTable = new HotelValentinoDataSet.KorisniciDataTable();
        HotelValentinoDataSetTableAdapters.KorisniciTableAdapter korisnikAdapter = new HotelValentinoDataSetTableAdapters.KorisniciTableAdapter();
        korisnikAdapter.FillByUsernamePassword(korisnikTable, txtKorisnickoIme.Text, txtLozinka.Text);
        if (korisnikTable.Count > 0)
        {
            if (glavnauc == null)
            {
                glavnauc = new GlavnaUC();
                glavnauc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                Controls.Add(glavnauc);
            }
            glavnauc.BringToFront();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("WRONG data");
    }
```

//the code above is working ok, 
what i need now is to make some code to turn down the login form: 
after 2 wrong logins to pop up msgbox "You have one more try"
if its wrong third time the app. will close it self!

Answer (score 2):

The User information should hold the number of failed login attempts. 
The best place to put the check should be `FillByUsernamePassword`. It reads the number of failed login attempts for that particular user, if >=3 returns an error (or an empty table). If the number is less than 3 it attempts to validate the password.
If the password is correct it resets the number of failed login attempts to 0.

1. The number of failed login attempts should be per user.
2. It's not very user friendly (or safe) to tell the user how many attempts he has left.
3. Closing the app on 3 failures may be overkill. Perhaps there are other users who do know their passwords :)

Should the failed login attempts counter reset itself after some time?

Comment: Good thinking! Altought i have 1 observation; i have to set some global max tries to login if there is unuthorised user that cant be connected with any account in db. Thanks for you help